# Set Data Attribute using DataSet API

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

Following is the way to get data attribute from a tag using dataset api.

```
<div data-color="red">Apple</div>

var color = document.querySelector('div').dataset.color
```

1. How to set the data attribute?
2. Can I create new data attributes?
3. Will they automatically get appended to the element?

Please provide answer with example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can set the [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute via the same `dataset` you mentioned or with [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
2. Yes, as demonstrated in the code example below. You can do it with `dataset` or `setAttribute`.
3. Yup. CSS can style them because of this. See the `div[data-price]:after` style in my example.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var data = div.dataset;

div.innerHTML += ' was ' + data.color;

data.color = 'yellow';

div.innerHTML += '; now it is ' + data.color + '. <br/>';

data.type = 'Golden Delicious';

div.setAttribute('data-price', '$1.00');

div.innerHTML += 'This div has the following attribute/value pairs:';

for (var i = 0; i < div.attributes.length; i++) {
  var attr = div.attributes[i];
  div.innerHTML += '<br/>' + attr.name + '=' + attr.value;
}

div.innerHTML += '<br/>This div has the following dataset key/value pairs:';

for (var key in data) {
  div.innerHTML += '<br/>' + key + '=' + data[key];
}
```

```css
div[data-color=red] {
  color: red;
}
div[data-color=yellow] {
  color: goldenrod;
}
div[data-price]:after {
  content: attr(data-price);
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div data-color="red">Apple</div>
```